# Unused variable warning (editor) array_walk

Tags: php, arrays

Following code generates an editor warning for not using `$key` in the code. Any idea how to avoid this warning? Is there any similar check done by the `PHP` parses too?

```
array_walk($services, function(&$value, $key) {
    $value = str_replace('xxx', '', $value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual documentation for `array_walk`](http://php.net/array_walk):

> Typically, callback takes on two parameters. The array parameter's value being the first, and the key/index second.

You can simply omit the `$key` as it isn't being used inside the callback function.

```
array_walk($services, function(&$value) {
    $value = str_replace('xxx', '', $value);
});
```

It's important to note that what you have is perfectly valid PHP code. Just [enable error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393) (if you haven't already) and fix any errors the PHP parser throws. There's no reason to change it just because your IDE complains so. In this particular case, it doesn't matter though.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove it.

```
array_walk($services, function(&$value) {
    $value = str_replace('xxx', '', $value);
});
```

But note it's an editor warning, it's **not PHP warning**.